# Dead Lock with JBoss Cache 1.4.1

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, concurrency, deadlock, second-level-cache

I'm use: JBoss AS 4.2.3, JBoss Cache 1.4.1 SP12, Hibernate 3.2.6; JPA 1.0.1
with

```
<attribute name="NodeLockingScheme">PESSIMISTIC</attribute>
<attribute name="IsolationLevel">READ_COMMITTED</attribute>
```

and

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.cache.usage" value="transactional"/>
<property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class"
          value="org.hibernate.cache.TreeCacheProvider"/>
<property name="hibernate.treecache.local_puts_only" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.treecache.querycache.local_writes_only" value="true"/>
```

settings;

I have such entity:

```
@Entity  
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL, region = "AccountCache")  
public class Account {  
    ...some fields and methods...  
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
public class User {
    ....
    @ManyToOne
    private Account account;
    ....
}
```

So, I have timer service, that get information about `Account` and do some thing (not change `Account`, just get, and change some another entity). When user loggin, and work in pages (switch pages, do some thing in it (not change `Account` or `User` entity)), and when at this moment timer service starts work, user page blocked, and after 15 second throws error:

```
....many lines of stack and such errors...
Error performing load command
org.hibernate.cache.CacheException: org.jboss.cache.lock.TimeoutException: 
failure acquiring lock: fqn=/default/AccountCache, 
caller=Thread[http-192.0.2.58-80-6,5,jboss], lock=write 
owner=GlobalTransaction:<null>:88 (org.jboss.cache.lock.LockStrategyReadCommitted@63b596)
....many lines of stack and such errors...
```

It seems, that `GlobalTransaction:<null>:88` is user tx, and `caller` is `timer service`.

Usually user thread works fine, less than 15 seconds. If disable `@Cache` in `Account` all work fine (it seems).

If enable `Optimistic` lock scheme, in same concurrency (some times) throws such error:

```
Caused by: org.jboss.cache.optimistic.DataVersioningException:
Tx attempted to create /default/AccountCache/com.****.entity.account.Account#1 anew.
It has already been created since this tx started by another (possibly remote) tx.
```

And question))) 
What's the problem? Is `TreeCache` problem, or my app problem?
What I do wrong? All transaction managed by container...

Comment: Are you using the cache provider suggested in http://galder.zamarreno.com/?p=56 which was later updated in http://galder.zamarreno.com/?p=227 ? See http://community.jboss.org/wiki/NewJBossCache14xBasedHibernate32CacheProvider for more info. This cache provider is designed to avoid lock problems.

Comment: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/NewJBossCache14xBasedHibernate32CacheProvider

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing cache first, by deleting physical file or programmatically. If not, try using `<attribute name="NodeLockingScheme">MVCC</attribute>`, Optimistic and pessimistic locking scheme are deprecated anyways.